# IBM Cognos- difference between burst key, burst group

Tags: cognos, cognos-10, cognos-bi

I'm new to bursting in cognos and would like to know what the difference between a burst key and burst group is.

Answer (score 0):

The words are used interchangeably. There is no real difference.